# what UUID to use in fstab to mount LVM ubuntu-vg root

Tags: mount, root, fstab, lvm

I moved root to LVM. The system is running, but I noticed a folder inside root that looks much like a UUID (53d4...) from the previous system. How can I remove this folder?

[image: (see folder inside root)]

inside folder:

[image: (inside folder)]

I am now wondering -- am I mounting root correctly? Something seems off.

This is the command I used to move root to the LVM partition (I had to do this from a live-cd):

`cp -aR '/media/user/53d4fe95-99ce-49dc-844c-165123990001/' '/home/user/tempmount'`

/etc/fstab currently has:

```
# root at /dev/sdb1
UUID=a3434e96-3be4-4f4b-b8ca-751b36f0fd22 /     ext4 errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap at /dev/sdb1/
UUID=62ebffc9-81a6-4441-b1ee-e4862158150e none  swap sw                0       0
```

[image: My layout in Partition Manager]

the UUID of root in fstab is pointing to /dev/ubuntu-vm/root

[image: (see Partition Manager properties for /dev/ubuntu-vm/root)]

lvs

```
root@system:~# lvs -v
LV   VG        #Seg Attr       LSize   Maj Min KMaj KMin Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Cpy%Sync Log         Convert LV UUID                                LProfile
root ubuntu-vg    1 mwi-aom--- 214.84g  -1  -1  253    3                                100.00   [root_mlog]         pYS9i4-txAG-RUZ7-YGXe-iiLZ-29CW-WujyJr         
swap ubuntu-vg    3 -wi-ao----  16.64g  -1  -1  253    4                                                             NRw2y4-mj0A-DVFz-CuHu-PXn5-hxRu-xtKy6G
```

vgs

```
root@system:~# vgs -v
VG        Attr   Ext   #PV #LV #SN VSize VFree   VG UUID                                 VProfile
ubuntu-vg wz--n- 4.00m   3   2   0 1.58t 958.85g 0ihnWz-KuDC-8GcZ-j9Ls-dbG4-URKZ-wJ4DNV
```

Should I be using in fstab `UUID pYS9i4-txAG-RUZ7-YGXe-iiLZ-29CW-WujyJr` (from ubuntu-vg root) instead?

---

### UPDATE:

I changed sftab to this:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap none swap sw 0 0
```

and the system booted just fine.

What is that folder `53d4fe95-99ce-49dc-844c-165123990001` doing?

**How can I remove that folder?**

mount -l

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs    (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=8124076k,nr_inodes=2031019,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1630556k,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered) [root]
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/unified type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1428)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/dark-knight_1.snap on /snap/dark-knight/1 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4206.snap on /snap/core/4206 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/cumulonimbus_18.snap on /snap/cumulonimbus/18 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4017.snap on /snap/core/4017 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_4110.snap on /snap/core/4110 type squashfs (ro,nodev,relatime,x-gdu.hide)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/snapd/ns type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1630556k,mode=755)
nsfs on /run/snapd/ns/dark-knight.mnt type nsfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1630552k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
gvfsd-fuse on /home/nathaniel/.gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,relatime)
```

more from GNOME Commander

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help on how to remove this folder is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your screen shot shows that the uuid of ubuntu-vg/root is the one listed in /etc/fstab, so why are you asking if you should be using some other UUID that you say is from ubuntu-vg root, but isnt?

Comment: @psusi I added an update and more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you somehow managed to copy all of your files into that folder.  As long as all of your personal files are still in your home directory, you should be safe to remove that extra copy with `sudo rm -fr /53d4fe95-99ce-49dc-844c-165123990001/`.